# CoreAnimation rotation transformation animation direction

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

Is there a simple way to specify whether an image should rotate clockwise or anti-clockwise in objective C?  I have a speedometer with a needle (a design that reflects prices of automobiles) - it is working fine, except when it is closer for the needle to rotate down and out of the screen over to the other side.  I want it always to rotate counterclockwise to go to lower numbers and clockwise to go to higher numbers.  Here is my code segment:

```
// figure out the minimum and maximum prices shown on the 
// speedometer
float min = [_a.text floatValue] * 1000;
float max = [_g.text floatValue] * 1000;

// set calibration between number labels to be small or large
int cal = SMALL_CALIBRATION;
if ([_stickerPriceSetting floatValue] >= TRIGGERPRICE)
    cal = LARGE_CALIBRATION;

// set an animation duration of 1.5 seconds for the needle rotation
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];

// low prices (off speedometer)
if (price < (min - cal)) 
    _needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI/12); 

// price too high (off speedometer)
else if (price  > (max + cal)) 
    _needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 13/12); 

// need to have needle point to the price
else {
    float delta = (max - min);
    float price_point = price - min;
    _needle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(price_point/delta * M_PI);
}

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by animating the layer property `transform.rotation`:

```
// figure out the minimum and maximum prices shown on the 
// speedometer
float min = [_a.text floatValue] * 1000;
float max = [_g.text floatValue] * 1000;

// set calibration between number labels to be small or large
int cal = SMALL_CALIBRATION;
if ([_stickerPriceSetting floatValue] >= TRIGGERPRICE)
    cal = LARGE_CALIBRATION;

CGFloat angle;
if (price < min - cal)
    angle = -M_PI / 12;
else if (price > max + cal)
    angle = M_PI * 13 / 12;
else
    angle = M_PI * (price - min) / (max - min);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    [(id)_needle.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:angle]
        forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
}];
```

If you import `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h` you won't need the `(id)` cast.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a speedometer. You cannot specify the rotation direction when animating the transform-property. It will always take the shortest way. I solved the problem by doing 2 animations in case the angle is greater than 180 degrees (2nd animation starts after 1st finishes). You have to pay attention for the correct animation times so that it animates smooth.

Comment: This is kind of helpful to me - except I have no way of knowing if the angle from the original point to the new point is going to be greater than 180 degrees - unless there is an easy way to first find out what angle the needle (UIView) is currently at?  I am guessing I am going to have to write a bunch of code saving the old price and incorporating that into the needle movement.